# Remove trailing numbers from string js regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove the trailing numbers from  the string using JavaScript RegExp. Here is the example.

```
Input          output

-------------------------
string33     => string 
string_34    => string_
str_33_ing44 => str_33_ing
string       => string
```

Hope above example clears what I am looking for!

Comment: Describe to us, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this one /^(.*)(\d+)$/i. but it was missing missing not working

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use this regex to match all the trailing numbers.

```
\d+$
```

Then remove the matched digits with an empty string. `\d+` matches one or more digits. `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

```
string.replace(/\d+$/, "")
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `.replace()`:

```
"string".replace(/\d+$/, '')
```

A simple demo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8xvrze0/