# Removing int and float from the end of a string using Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I found an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690005/remove-trailing-numbers-from-string-js-regexp) that is almost perfect but I need a slight tweak. I've read the basics of regex and I'm using https://regex101.com/ but I can't figure it out.

Using `"string".replace(/\d+$/, '')` I can remove any numbers from the end of the string. However I also need to remove any numbers that have a format with a decimal like `#.#` or `##.#` as well as whole numbers, but **only when they appear at the end of the string.** From regex101 I have found that the `$` is for the end of the string.

I can use `.replace(/\d+([.]\d+)?/g)` to remove numbers and floats but it removes them from the entire string, not just when they appear at the end, and I can't work out where to put the `$` as I don't really understand regex yet and can't get it to work.

It seems such a small and stupid problem but I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to need `.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/, '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, perfect! I don't understand it but it does work, thank you. I will read up more about regex.

Comment: There is another /(\d+\.\d+)+$|\d+$/

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that doesn't parse int's/decimals correctly ? `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$` .. -1

Comment: @sln because I tested it and it worked for me on a live example.

Comment: @Lyall - Well, I just said it doesn't work. Your sample _you_ used is what _you_ think a int/float is, not what it really constitutes.

Comment: @sln Well I had a site that was displaying a int and a decimal (depending on the querystring) at the end, I added the suggested answer and it is no longer showing. Therefore as far as I'm concerned it works in the live environment and I accepted the answer. Can you prove it doesn't work? I don't feel the downvote is necessary considering this fixed my problem exactly.

Comment: @sln also I don't see what right you have to downvote a question because you think I have accepted the wrong answer when you yourself have not submitted an alternative answer that works any better. The answer I accepted works for me, so I accepted it. Thanks.

Comment: Your words: `to remove numbers and floats`. Go ahead and change that to `exclude valid floats that I don't think are valid` and I'll take off the downvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149168/discussion-between-lyall-and-sln).

Comment: @Lyall There are different locales, environments and just definitions of a "float" (or people also call it "decimal" interchangeably). For most human cases, `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` suffices. In computing, there are other "notations": `.5`, `1.2e+45`, `6.` are possible. Then, even [this pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) won't be enough. You can use [`\s*[-+]?(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/MFyXeC/2). But *universal* patterns can overfire. Use only the part that you need and do not listen to people who *tell* you what you need.

Comment: And if you need more advice on the regex implementation in your concrete context, feel free to drop me a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/, '')
```

The pattern matches

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - a *non-capturing group* (the `?:` makes it non-capturing, that is, you cannot access the value captured by this group) that matches an optional sequence of a `.` and then 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

To also remove any 0+ whitespaces before the number, add `\s*` (where `\s` matches any whitespace and `*` quantifier makes the regex engine match (consecutively) 0 or more of the characters matched with this pattern) at the pattern start.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MFyXeC/1).

Comment: Some more reference: [`$` anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1603/anchor-characters-dollar), [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/3832970), [regex quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#basics).