# How to remove only numbers from the end of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code to get a string and alert it after removing only the last number. Currently I have the following code. But here, remove all the numbers in the string including numbers where at the middle of the string. But I need to remove only the numbers where at the end of the string.

```
Ex - String = "ABC_1_XY_20"
     alert -> "ABC_1_XY_"
```

I need to keep "1" But now I lost it as well. How can I fix this?

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  var st = "ABC_1_XY_20".replace(/[\d\.]/g ,'');
  alert(st);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Note that `replace()` has nothing to do with jQuery. I've edited your question title as such.

Comment: You could also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690005/remove-trailing-numbers-from-string-js-regexp) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088488/removing-int-and-float-from-the-end-of-a-string-using-javascript-regex) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this use the `$` character class to denote that the match should be made at the end of the string. It also makes the `g` modifier redundant. You can also use `+` to repeated number and `.` characters at the end of the string. Try this:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var st = "ABC_1_XY_20".replace(/[\d\.]+$/, '');
  console.log(st);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: don need [ in your regex try \d+$ will do the same.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yes you do as the OP is replacing the `.` as well as the numbers.

Comment: @DavidJohns no problem, glad to help

Comment: Most of the characters enclosed by square brackets are already matched literally, thus the backslash behind the dot is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this, it removes the las digit(\d) from your string

```js
var st = "ABC_1_XY_201".replace(/\d$/ ,'');
  console.log(st);
```

Comment: Note that the example in the question removes all the ending number and `.` characters, not just one of them

Comment: not want to remove the last number?, want to remove all numbers at the end of string. Ok

Comment: Yes, need to remove all numbers at the end. I showed it in my example in the question.